# How to move data to a bigger SD card (internal storage)?

Tags: 8.1-oreo, internal-sd, motorola-moto-g5

I have a Moto G5 with Android 8.1. My 128 Gb micro sd card is formatted as internal, and I want to replace it with a bigger one (and I want to still use it as an internal storage).
Is it any way I can migrate my data to the new memory card?

Answer (score -1):

Your new memory card will be wiped anyway when you insert it into your phone for the first time. So I would recommend copying the data to the new memory card after you insert it. You can copy it using OTG or via computer.